# Inverse vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Suppose $Mx=z$ Where $M$ is a matrix, $x$ and $z$ are column vectors. $M$ is unknown but I know $x$ and $z$. Can I obtain $My$ by $My=Mxx^{-1}y=zx^{-1}y$?

Edited

As pointed out by @Rahul and @Velutluna that I can not do it in this way. If I know $x$ and $z$, how can I compute $My$ without trying to compute $M$? Since in my program large number of iterations evolving this, it will be very time consuming to compute $M$ each time.

Comment: So $x^{-1}$ is a row vector?

Comment: @angryavian I don't know what $x^{-1}$ should be like, this is a general expression.

Comment: The motivation for the question is a little hard to follow, but it seems like you know $x$ and $Mx$ and want to use them to compute $My$ from $y$? Of course this is not possible, for example if $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$, then $Mx$ is the first column of $M$; that tells you nothing about $My$ which is the second column.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks. I have edited my question, How can I obtain $My$ if I know $x$ and $z$ and $Mx=z$, without computing $M$?

Comment: I don't understand. In my comment I said that you cannot obtain $My$ when you only have $x$ and $Mx$. Now it sounds like you are still asking how to obtain $My$ when you only have $x$ and $Mx$. What's the difference??

Comment: Sorry. I missed something in your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the non-zero column vector as an $n \times 1$ matrix. Then of course it has full column rank. Hence the left inverse exists. For $n \ne 1$, it cannot have both left and right inverse. Hence the right inverse appearing in your equation does not exist.